# Keyboard and Wacom Bamboo tablet lagging on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, keyboard

## Context

I have a multi-boot computer, in which I installed few days ago a Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

I use with it:

- an usb mouse Logitec
- an usb keyboard Logitec
- a Wacom Bamboo CTH-461 tablet

## Problem

After a little time on (20-30 minutes), my keyboard starts to lag: I have to write very slowly (~2 press/sec max) if I want all the letters (if I go faster, some of them are not written). Example: my first line of letters on my keyboard are `azertyuiop` ; if I press them quickly, it writes `azryiop`.

I have a similar problem with the tablet: cursor moves are lagging.

The problem happens before I tried to plug my tablet on, but I note it here because it seems to affect both keyboard and tablet, but not the mouse.

It happens in all the programs (web browser, text editor, terminal, Krita...).

Do you have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Ok, it seems to come from Teamspeak: if I open it, after a few time, my keyboard starts to lag. Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after updates of my system and Teamspeak. I don't know which specifically solved the problem.